# Calling new command from user defined name

Tags: packages

Have made a library containing some style files.  In my `.bashrc` I have added the library directory using the `TEXINPUTS` environment variable.  Is  `TEXINPUTS` commonly empty when using `texlive` ?

```
typex="${HOME}/Opstk"
export TEXINPUTS=".:${typex}//:${TEXINPUTS}"
```

I am using `//` to look into subdirectories, but unsure whether to use the `.:` at the start.

In style file `piston.sty` I set

```
%% piston.sty

\makeatletter
\catcode`-=11

\RequirePackage{geometry}

\newcommand{\piston-alumin-pg}
              {\geometry{
                 paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
                 textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm,
                 left=8mm, right=8mm, top=8mm, bottom=8mm}}
```

Then have the ability for the user to change the name by modifying the file `userdef.sty`.

```
%% userdef.sty

\RequirePackage{piston}

\newcommand{\wvAluminPg}{\piston-alumin-pg}

\makeatother
\catcode`\-=12
```

Would the following be the appropriate way to construct a document that uses the new command for defining a new page size ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\RequirePackage{userdef}

\wvAluminPg

\begin{document}

Some Text Here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please ask these questions separately. SE operates a one question per question thing. Why do you want to do either of these things in these ways? Why mess around with TEXINPUTS rather than just putting the files where they'll be found? `\makeatletter` is pointless in a `.sty`. Why are you changing catcodes? Is there any reason to need to modify the name of the command? If there really is, why the roundabout approach? Why not a package option? What's the use case for this when people could as easily load `geometry`?

Comment: The final blockshould be `\usepackage` not `\Requirepackage` 9even though they are the same thing) but why the use of `-` here not `@ (latex2e style) or `_` (expl3 style) for the internal command?

Comment: You don't need the trailing `${TEXINPUTS}`; just a trailing colon suffices (and is better).

Comment: @cfr The question is not about arguing with my choices.  The question is about using the style file `userdef.sty` in the way things have been set up as one question, not three as you state.

Comment: @Veak People commonly ask questions which constitute XY problems or they post code which is problematic in ways they may not appreciate. I know the question is not about your choices, but neither is a comment an answer. And I'm not the only one raising concerns. Besides, it is often impossible to provide a good answer without understanding *why* an OP wants to do something.

Comment: Questioning your choices can help both you and others. Since the site is supposed to help everyone, not just you, providing answers to problems that are fundamentally misguided isn't necessarily a good thing. So if you're doing things that people think are misguided you should expect to get questions about them, since that might help you too.

Comment: There are questions about `TEXINPUTS` at the top (one explicit, one implicit) and then an unrelated (as far as I can tell) question about using a `.sty` in a document. `TEXINPUTS` is not empty for me and I'm using TeX Live. I doubt it should be empty. You need the initial dot if you want files in your working directory to be found.

Comment: Have thought about this well.  Let's not start with the insults.  I always win !

Comment: I simply want to call the command `\wvAluminPg` in my document, and have shown the setup that I have to make it work.  It is misguided to insist upon one question only when there are interrelations within a given question.

Comment: I do not believe I insulted you. If you feel differently, I'm sorry about that. But, as @AlanMunn tried to explain, asking questions about what you're doing and why is legitimate and common. Even if you personally have very good reasons for doing things differently, your code and any answers are liable to be copied by others. Since what you're doing would generally not be a good idea, that's potentially a problem. It can be mitigated if answers (and, ideally, your question) make the special circumstances clear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use hyphen as I code much in `lisp`.  Would I need no change any catcodes to use `_` as one does with `@` ?

Comment: @Veak `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` switches on syntax for the `expl3` programming layer. Note that this also means spaces are discarded, so you need `~` or similar if you actually want a space.

Comment: Had some experience of people insisting that I am wrong and misguided.  It is perfectly valid to sort things the way I did.  Although some may not like it, the copying of this by others is not a crime.  I understand that the way I do things is not something one sees everyday.

Comment: Because I call `\wvAluminPg`, would I really need to specify `a4paper` when using `\documentclass` as in `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`.

Comment: @cfr Then I would say that I need `\ExplSyntaxOff` at the end of `userdef.sty`.

Comment: but it's so dangerous to change `-` depending what else you are doing, you will break a lot of code, negative numbers, overbar accents, table markup, ... all likely to break.

Comment: why would a user in `userdef` define a command then call it in the document? surely `\newcommand{\wvAluminPg}{\piston-alumin-pg}` could simply be `\piston-alumin-pg`

Comment: In case the user wants to use his own names he can redefine what he wants.  Otherwise do as you say.

Comment: I only use hyphen within my style file. Users will continue using the usual commands with the `hyphen`.  Perhaps I am doing something wrong though and would require a new question.

Comment: @egreg You mean `export TEXINPUTS=".:${typex}//:"` ?

Comment: `less $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFDIST)/web2c/texmf.cnf`, `texconfig conf` and/or `tlmgr conf`.

Comment: yes but you have not shown your package, will you never need a negative length or negative number in your package code? certainly you should restore `-` at the end of piston.sty not leave it catcode11, or a document that uses `\usepackage{piston}` directly will be broken.

Comment: You are right.  With `\usepackage{piston}` directly, the document would break.  The reality is that `piston` is to be a sub-package of a larger one.  `piston.sty` is just one of the files. No, I do not use `-` for negative numbers in my package.  Would `_` also cause problems as it is used in other special contexts as well.

Comment: Can one conclude that the recommendation is not to leave  hyphen `-` with `catcode11`.  Shouldn't that advice also apply to `\ExplSyntaxOff` ?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you're doing and why.  It seems like you want others to be able to use your style files, and trust them enough to tell them how to modify their bashrc file to point to your library.  But then why not do things the usual way and put the files into texmf-local?  And why have separate (sub)packages where one brittlely turns off something another turned on? As a separate question, you want to have users be able to customize a command name.  But why have them edit a style file, instead of `\newcommand{\csname #1\endcsname}}{...}`?  And why `-` instead of `@`?

Comment: Have changed from using `-` or `@` to `_`.   About customising commands, I am still writing my first package and you might be right.

Comment: " Shouldn't that advice also apply to `\ExplSyntaxOff `?" yes most certainly, any file that has `\ExplSyntaxOn` should have `\ExplSyntaxOff ` before closing.

Comment: if you want others to use the package, don't rely on TEXINPUTS, and also don't use generic names like `userdef` (which most likely would not be accepted by texlive anyway) use names associated to your package.